# Artificial Marking On synthesized image using GAN

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, generative-adversarial-network

I have a problem with generated images from PGGAN (Progressive Growing of GANs) which I have generated some. Grid format images are synthetic images from GAN and the single image is a Real image sample as shown with this post. How can I remove this artificial marking on synthesized images which I highlighted in Grid format images?

Synthesized image

[image: Synthesized image]

Real Image

[image: Real Image]

Comment: Can you make one of the synthesized images larger? What is the difference between the artificial markings you speak of and the real ones? It's not obvious from your post.

Comment: @Ken4scholars I give the image sample in the Answer section please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Ken4scholars here is the larger version can you see the in the background which I underlined there are some artificial marking why is that and what do you think this generation of synthesized image is good or not.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGna9.png)